# Hold Old and New value in SaveChange as DbEntityEntry.Entity to Audit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, audit, audit.net

As you know we can Audit object in `SaveChange()` but I have some problem with Modified and Deleted entities as following,

First I am using [Audit.Net](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET)(this is very simple to use) to Audit my objects the below method should do audit as:

```
 private int SaveAuditRecord(DbEntityEntry dbEntry, string userGUID)
    {
        Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "Saving Audid Entry{0}....", dbEntry.ToString());
        DateTime changeTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TableAttribute tableAttr = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault() as TableAttribute;
        string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : dbEntry.Entity.GetType().Name;
        Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "TableName Retrived {0}...", tableName);
        switch (dbEntry.State)
        {
            case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added:
                int result = base.SaveChanges(); 
                AuditNet.AuditMonoAction("Add " + tableName, userGUID, dbEntry.Entity);
                return result;
            case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted:
                AuditNet.AuditMonoAction("Delete " + tableName, userGUID, dbEntry.Entity);
                break;
            case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified:
                int modifiedResult = 0;
                var primaryKey = GetPrimaryKeyValue(dbEntry);
                modifiedResult = base.SaveChanges(); 
                object entity2Audit = dbEntry.Entity;//Hold the current entity here and change it in below Audit using block
                using (var audit = Audit.Core.AuditScope.Create("Edit " + tableName, () => dbEntry.Entity))
                { 
                    audit.SetCustomField("UserGUID", userGUID, false);  
                    foreach (var prop in dbEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                    {
                        var originalValue = dbEntry.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
                        var currentValue = dbEntry.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
                        if (originalValue != currentValue)
                            Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "Prop {0} get originalValue :{1} , currentValue:{2}", prop, originalValue, currentValue);
                    } 
                }
                return modifiedResult;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

1- For Added state there is no problem with because I am auditing `dbEntry.Entity` which I think contains Current Values always.

2- For `Delete` and `Modify` there is some problems,

Delete: I think as I am auditing `dbEntry.Entity`, it is looking for current value and raise the exception:

> > CurrentValues cannot be used for entities in the Deleted state.

Modify: always `OldValue` and `NewValue` always are the same as `CurrentValue` as I mentioned above.

So my main question is How can I do it for Delete and Modify like `dbEntry.Entity`?

P.S:
in Using block we can change audit object to set NewValue as [Audit.Net](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) mentioned.

**UPDATE1:**

Even with this code Old and New value always are the same :

```
 int modRes = 0;
                object entity2Audit = dbEntry.Entity;//Hold the current entity here and change it in below Audit using block
                DbEntityEntry dbEntryTemp = dbEntry;
                foreach (var prop in dbEntryTemp.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    var originalValue = dbEntry.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
                    var currentValue = dbEntry.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
                    if (originalValue != currentValue)
                    {
                        Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Error, "Prop11 {0} get originalValue :{1} , currentValue:{2}", prop, originalValue, currentValue);
                        dbEntryTemp.CurrentValues[prop] = dbEntryTemp.OriginalValues[prop] = originalValue;
                    }
                } 
                object en = dbEntryTemp.Entity;
                using (var audit = Audit.Core.AuditScope.Create("Edit " + tableName, () => en))
                {
                    modRes = base.SaveChanges();
                    audit.SetCustomField("UserGUID", userGUID, false);
                    audit.SetCustomField("NewValue", dbEntry.Entity, false);
                    audit.SetCustomField("OldValue", en, false);
                    en = dbEntry.Entity;
                }
```

Comment: Resolved but tomorrow can be posted as answer!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I should thanks to [thepirat000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122195/thepirat000) who made Audit.Net lib, this is very nice lib to Audit with many option as he mentioned in GitHub

but about my problem, this is my first time to override `SaveChange()` and I didn't know `DbEntityEntry` object as well, but the solution seems so funny, just need to convert `CurrentValues` and `OriginalValues` to `Object()`, in modify case I am getting the old value by `dbEntry.OriginalValues.ToObject()` and change it with `dbEntry.CurrentValues.ToObject()` in [Audit.Net](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) scope, that is all.

```
  Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Prompt, "Saving Audid Entry{0}....", dbEntry.ToString()); 
        TableAttribute tableAttr = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault() as TableAttribute;
        string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : dbEntry.Entity.GetType().Name;
        Logging.Log(LoggingMode.Prompt, "TableName Retrived {0}...", tableName);
        switch (dbEntry.State)
        {
            case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added:
                int result = base.SaveChanges();
                object addedObj = dbEntry.Entity;
                using (var audit = Audit.Core.AuditScope.Create("Add " + tableName, () =>addedObj ))
                {
                    audit.SetCustomField("UserGUID", userGUID);
                    addedObj = null;
                } 
                return result;
            case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted:
                object deletedObj = dbEntry.Entity;
                using (var audit = Audit.Core.AuditScope.Create("Delete " + tableName, () => deletedObj))
                {
                    audit.SetCustomField("UserGUID", userGUID);
                    deletedObj = null;
                }  
                break;
            case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified: 
                object en = dbEntry.OriginalValues.ToObject();
                using (var audit = Audit.Core.AuditScope.Create("Edit " + tableName, () => en))
                {
                    audit.SetCustomField("UserGUID", userGUID);
                    en = dbEntry.CurrentValues.ToObject();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
```