# EF 6 DB First Audit Logs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, audit, audit-trail

I have a EF 6 DB first MVC 5 application. My requirement is to do audit logging of every operation (including read). I went through many posts and have few queries:

1. Should audit logging be done at EF level (by overriding SaveChanges) or DB level (by using triggers). Which is the recommended way.
2. I want to log one row per entity change instead of per property change. What am I thinking is to make a valid XML schema but then each entity will have different schema depending on the column. Any other inputs on how to achieve this
3. I want log for read operation too
4. Last thing is, client wants to maintain checksum value per row using SHA3 or MD5.

Considering above points, what is the suggested approach. I could really use some pointers.

Comment: If you want to audit even read then you need to implement a wrapper for your DBContext and then audit the operation of `wrapper` , `SaveChanges()` can audit `Added` and `Modified` entity not read entity like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466550/hold-old-and-new-value-in-savechange-as-dbentityentry-entity-to-audit, if your audit is complicated then use the proper `Audit` utility.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, any recommended `Audit` utility? I see that you used `Audit.Net`

Comment: You are Welcome, yes I am using `Audit.Net` it is power and reliable, before this I implemented my custom audit which was not proper and reliable, it will give you `Old` and `New` value as you expected, but for auditing `Select` you should implement it such as a wrapper.

Comment: Yes `Read` is really problematic and i am not sure how detailed will you go in it. Using Navigation properties you can read multiple entries while reading only one. That's why I asked point 1 whether I should go with DB triggers.

Comment: No, I think it is not worth used DB trigger to know if row read or not, Suppose you have an entity named `Entity` then it is enough to implement a class for sample named  `EntityManagement` which have a method named `Get(id)` which returns specific `Entity` then in `Get(id)` you can do `Read Audit`, I think the `DBContext` should not be accessible out, `DbContext` should used in some wrapper, then if a developer need to manipulate data the should use those wrapper not `DbContext` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, I did not use any utility as my requirements were bit different. Finally I went ahead with overriding the `SaveChanges` method of `DbContext` used by EF. Also used Newtonsoft JSON library to convert whole updated object to JSON and save it.

To get complete code, check this link - [How to audit MVC app which used EF DB first approach](https://mysharepointlearnings.wordpress.com/2019/01/29/auditing-in-mvc-ef-project/)